# how to truncate last element if needed

Tags: css

I have a div with different number of span inside depending on my code, my problem is, sometimes the last span does not fit the space and everything lost the align, what I want to do is applied my "truncate" class to the last element if needed, there is an example:

```
<div class="truncate">
   <span> ONE </span>
   <span> TWO </span>
   <span> THREE </span>
   <span> FOUR </span>
</div>

.truncate {
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

with this configuration, and also aplying "truncate" everything moved to left, and I stop watching "one" instead "four" as I want, either the "..." are not shown.

I also tried aplied truncate to the last child with same result:

```
.truncate:last-child {
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) pseudo-class.

Comment: Thanks, but as I comented in the post, it also happens if I include the class to the last child

Answer (score 0):

Might not be relevant to you now, but I had this problem, and I solved it with `flex-shrink: 0` which tells certain elements never to shrink, which means that last element shrinks.

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/68usz20p/2/

[image: screenshot of solution showing last child truncating]

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 175px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1ch;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

div span:last-child {
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can using css `:last-child` Selector

```css
.truncate span:last-child {
 display:none; visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="truncate">
   <span> ONE </span>
   <span> TWO </span>
   <span> THREE </span>
   <span> FOUR </span>
</div>
```

Preview at https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/yt9srxLo/